# Select all table entries which have a fully capitalized string in a specific column?

Tags: sql

I have a database table with a few thousand entries. A part of the entries (~20%) have been entered with a fully capitalized strings in the 'name' column.

Example:

```
id | name
---------
1 | THOMAS GOLDENBERG
2 | Henry Samuel
3 | GIL DOFT
4 | HARRY CRAFT
5 | Susan Etwall
6 | Carl Cooper
```

How would an SQL query look like that selects all entries with a fully capitalized string in the name column? (i.e. in the example: those with the ID 1,3,4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MySQL it would be:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = UPPER(name);
```

I think this would work the same way in SQL Server, DB2 and Postgres.

Comment: At least in Microsoft SQL Server, you need to make sure that you have a collation which is case sensitive, otherwise each record will match your query.

Comment: I'm not aware of collation issues with Oracle, but UPPER is supported.

Answer (score 4):

What database system?

In theory you can do a simple `SELECT ... WHERE name = UPPER(name);` but that does not always work. Depending on the collation of your data, you may found that *all* records satisfy this condition because the comparison used may be case insensitive.

You need to ensure you compare using a case sensitive collation, and the correct answer depends on the database platform you use. For example, using SQL Server syntax:

```
SELECT ... WHERE Name COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS = UPPER(Name);
```

This also [works in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html) with the condition that you use a collation name valid on MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from your_table where name = upper(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a MySql function to convert uppercase to title case:

example:

```
update your_table set name = tcase(name) where name = upper(name);
```

function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `tcase`(str text) RETURNS text CHARSET latin1
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

  DECLARE result TEXT default '';
  DECLARE space INT default 0;
  DECLARE last_space INT default 0;

  IF (str IS NULL) THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;    

  IF (char_length(str) = 0) THEN
    RETURN '';
  END IF;

  SET result = upper(left(str,1));
  SET space = locate(' ', str);    

  WHILE space > 0 DO            
    SET result = CONCAT(result, SUBSTRING(str, last_space+2, space-last_space-1));            
    SET result = CONCAT(result, UPPER(SUBSTRING(str, space+1, 1)));        
    SET last_space = space;
    SET space = locate(' ', str, space+2);    
  END WHILE;

  SET result = CONCAT(result, SUBSTRING(str, last_space+2));

  RETURN result;

END $$    
DELIMITER ;
```